# Tool for merging Java classes and interfaces

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm a Java software developer and often inherit existing projects. These projects follow the convention that each class has an interface even if there is only one implementation.

I would like to merge the interface and the implementation. Does anyone know a tool that supports this merge for a given source folder. The tool may have some flaws but it should automate most of the work. It is ok to adjust a few things afterwards manually.

Here is an example. There is a file `MyService.java` for the interface:

```
package my.package;

/**
 * some comment on the interface
 */
public interface MyService {
    /**
     * another comment on the interface
     */
    Object doSomething();
}
```

and the implementation file `MyServiceImpl.java`

```
package my.package;

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
    public Object doSomething() {
        //the implementation
    }

    private void doSomethingElse() {
        ....
    }
}
```

I would like the tool to replace `MyService.java` with

```
package my.package;

/**
 * some comment on the interface
 */
public class MyService {
    /**
     * another comment on the interface
     */
    public Object doSomething() {
        //the implementation
    }

    private void doSomethingElse() {
        ....
    }
}
```

and replace `MyServiceImpl` in all other files with `MyService`.

Comment: Always having an interface is usually considered a **good** idea so why take a step backwards. See: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1998/jw-12-techniques.html?page=1

Comment: There are different opinions on this topic: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it I belong to the party who considers this to be a **bad** idea.